# When I have to use the verb Sein instead of the verb Werden (passive voice)?

Tags: passive

Why this is correct?

> Er war überrascht.

And this is **not** correct:

> Er wurde überrascht.

Comment: The question is (obviously) missing context as both sentences are correct German - but they simply mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

The difference has nothing to do with grammar: both are correct.

> Er war überrascht.

This is not passive voice. It describes the state that he is in, as in "He is surprised" or "He is tired".

> Er wurde überrascht.

This is passive voice. It is about an action that happened to him, meaning that someone somehow surprised him.

Comment: The terminology isn't standard and sometimes confusing. Some call the *sein* form either sein-passiv(e) or *Zustandpassiv*, and I've also seen "Statal" Passive. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice) notes a difference between dynamic and stative uses of the passive voice, for which English uses the same form: "The dog is fed every day." vs. "The dog is fed so we can leave." German would use the *werden* from in the first case and the *sein* in the second. In English you can replace "is" with "is being" in "The dog is being fed every day." It's not necessary though.